# Мне необходимо остановить последующее выполнение кода, а также оставить его в том же Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Мне необходимо остановить последующее выполнение кода,оставить его без изменений если условие if=true, а также оставить его в том же Activity... в том моменте, где это прописано комментарием на русском :

```
 String quantityString = mQuantityEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String soldString = mSoldEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    // This converts image into a byteArray so that it can be saved in the database.
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable();
    // Check if an image was selected, if not, then return
    if (bitmapDrawable == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.editor_image_not_selected),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   //Здесь мне необходимо остановить извлечение кода, а также оставить его в положении до этой строки, для того чтобы Юзер ввел свои данные 

}


Bitmap imageBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: может быть Вы имели ввиду не "извлечение" а "выполнение"?

Comment: Да, выполнение..

Comment: Вместо комментария напишите `return;`

Comment: Return выбрасывает меня в другой Activity(Главный), мне нужно остаться в этом, чтобы дать Юзеру возможность дозаполнить данные

Comment: `return` не может никуда выбрасывать. Вы наверное путаете с `finish()`. Если действительно не работает `return`, значит проблема в другом коде. Покажите полный код активити.

Comment: Это полный проект: (https://github.com/scooltr/Inventory). В EditorActivity часть кода упомянутого выше, код выбрасывает в CatalogActvity